# Rails boolean values and callbacks to default to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, boolean

UPDATE:
If the after_validation callback is used, it works as desired (e.g. the `false` value is persistent).  Still would like to know why that is, but I guess this is solved for my purposes :)

For a boolean field, I would like a callback in the model to set the default value to `false` instead of `nil`.

Currently when I create a new record, it initially shows the value as `false`, but then shows it as `nil`.

Wondering what's going on here and if the desired behavior is possible w/ a callback.

This is in the model:

```
  after_save :default_is_forsale

  def default_is_forsale
    self.not_for_sale = false if self.not_for_sale.nil?
  end
```

Here is the rails console output (irrelevant bits omitted):

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > Item.create(name: "thing 4")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (6.4ms)  INSERT INTO items [...]
   (190.8ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Item id: 20, name: "thing 4", not_for_sale: false>
```

Cool, created the new record with a default value of `false`.  But when I check again:

```
1.9.3p125 :002 > Item.last
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT [...]
 => #<Item id: 20, name: "thing 4", not_for_sale: nil>
```

Weird, now the value is `nil`.

But if I create a new record and explicitly set the value to `false`, it acts as I'd expect:

```
1.9.3p125 :003 > Item.create(name: "more thing", not_for_sale: false)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO items [...]
   (225.2ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Item id: 21, name: "more thing", not_for_sale: false>
```

When retrieved, the record still shows its boolean value of `false`

```
1.9.3p125 :004 > Item.last
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT [...]
=> #<Item id: 21, name: "more thing", not_for_sale: false>
```

BTW, I read elsewhere that the desired result is achievable via db migrations, but I am new to rails and would like to accomplish it through the model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your migration to set this boolean to false, as default. if there was code i'd show you.

I just read you were 'new to rails' but that doesn't matter. You don't need to do it in the model, unless you want that record to be true.

Comment: Thanks pjammer!  Doing it in the migration seems like the more pragmatic approach, but on the other hand it seems like the "rails way" is to do it in the model

Comment: seeing as migrations are the MOST railsy one could get, i'd be inclined to think doing less with less code is the rails way mate.

Answer (score 0):

You want this in a `before_save` callback. The `after_save` callback is called, unsurprisingly, *after* the record has already been saved.

Comment: Thanks xnm!  The `before_save` callback returns an error with the id (id = nil).  But this explains why `after_validation` works...